# Quick_Sort in Python does not work while trying on larger container

Tags: python, quicksort

I have implemented `quick_sort` from the scratch using basic ideas and tested on array with length of 100. It worked well. But then switched to the larger `array` (`len() == 10000`) and in addition, set recursion limit higher. In spite of that, It exits with no output without causing no error but as you would notice I want to record the time it takes to sort this array in order to compare with various algorithms.

```
from time import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7)

def swap(container, i, j):
    if container[i] != container[j]:
        container[i], container[j] = container[j], container[i]

d1 = time()
def partition(container, pivot_idx, P_idx):
    if pivot_idx < P_idx:
        pivot_idx = quick_sort(container, pivot_idx, P_idx)
        partition(container, pivot_idx, pivot_idx - 1)
        partition(container, pivot_idx + 1, P_idx)
d2 = time()
duration1 = d2 - d1

def quick_sort(container, pivot_idx, P_idx):
    pivot = container[pivot_idx]

    while P_idx > pivot_idx and container[P_idx] >= pivot:
        P_idx -=1
    
    i = P_idx

    while container[i] < pivot and i >= pivot_idx:
        i -=1
    
    swap(container, i, P_idx)

    return pivot_idx 


container = [i for i in range(10000, -1, -1)]

partition(container, 0, len(container) - 1)
print(f"quick_s:{duration1}")
```

Any recommendation..

Comment: First suggestion for timing is to randomize the order of your input data with `random.shuffle` or something similar and perform many trials. All you're timing here is the algorithm's performance on a reverse-sorted list, it's different than timing the general performance.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your timer is being measured before the definition of `partition()` and after `partition()` has been defined.  Shouldn't your times be taken before and after `partition()` is being called?

Comment: In addition, use `timeit` for this, don't write your own timer. Even `timeit` has its flaws but I guarantee it's better than rolling your own.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I ran this code with input of length 10000 and it completed in under one minute. Please provide details on how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Yeah, i am checking worst-case scenario for each algorithm and then compare.

Comment: @MichaelRuth it took the same for me, too. So did it complete with some output(printing sorted arr) or just exited without any?

Comment: I suspect that you're hitting a hard stack size limit that causes Python itself to quit rather than raising an exception.  Messing with `sys.recursionlimit` is bad IMO -- you need to fix your algorithm (or accept that it has a hard cap on input size) rather than trying to find ways to grow the stack bigger.

Comment: A few things to note: You've named your `quick_sort` and `partition` functions backwards, so `quick_sort` is doing the partitioning and `partition` is the top-level sort function. That won't make it run incorrectly, but does make it confusing. Next, your timing code is measuring how long it takes to define the `partition` function, not how long it takes to run it. Move that code down to where you call `partition()` just before you print out the duration. Lastly, the quicksort algorithm is very sensitive to the choice of pivot, picking a better one might let you avoid worst-case recursion.

Comment: @user20210310, why would you expect the code to print anything other than the duration? The only `print` statement is `print(f"quick_s:{duration1}")`. I did check `container` after the sort finished and it was sorted correctly.